# How to run reaction commerce in the background forever?

Tags: node.js, meteor, e-commerce, reaction-commerce

I am using reaction commerce https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction.

I tried `reaction &`. It will eventually die.

How do I run reaction commence in background forever?

Answer (score 0):

by [deploying](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/reaction-docs/master/deploying-reaction-using-docker)

or in short, build a docker image:

```
docker build --build-arg TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--max-old-space-size=2048" -t mycustom .
```

then run it:

```
docker run -d \
  -p 80:3000 \
  -e ROOT_URL="http://<your app url>" \
  -e MONGO_URL="mongodb://<your mongo url>" \
  -e REACTION_EMAIL="youradmin@yourdomain.com" \
  -e REACTION_USER="admin-username" \
  -e REACTION_AUTH="admin-password" \
  mydockerhubuser/mycustom:mytag
```